# Is the question about Characteristics − Manga attributes really too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

So, this question about [Characteristics − Manga attributes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13256/characteristics-%E2%88%92-manga-attributes) is currently on-hold and I also give a vote close to this question, but when I think again, is this question really too broad?

I'll give you some points here:

- OP only ask for the differences on characteristics between a comic and a manga. In my understanding (I might be wrong), he asks about what are the differences between how the characters are drawn in a comic and manga. Not the difference between comics and a manga as a whole media.
- This question got a link to [a question about What differentiates anime from regular cartoons?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-differentiates-anime-from-regular-cartoons) Compared with this, that question is way broader. And it's not a dupe, because while the question is related to each other, this question only asks about differences between how the characters are drawn (first point).
- Comics **really varies** around the world. This is basically everywhere except Japan. So it might be still too broad. So instead of asking a question about comics as general, this question might can be reworded with *Western/American Comics* compared with *Japanese manga.* But even with this, I still don't know how varies western comics are. I only know a few comics like Marvel, DC Comics and Disney. So, this might be a reason not to reopen this question.

Comment: I do find the difference in treatment of this question and the previous one to be somewhat unusual. See [this meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/153/is-what-differentiates-anime-from-regular-cartoons-off-topic) for the reasoning behind keeping that one open. We've debated it several times since then, to little avail and with no consensus. I don't really care about either question individually, but I would prefer if we were consistent on how we dealt with these two.

Comment: I agree with you that my question wasn't clear enough. I can edit and specify it. I also didn't found the other question who was quite similar to mine, but when is look at this other question, i think she is at least as broad as mine...
but if id would help i also can delete my question, it's not that big deal.

Comment: @BBallBoy you don't have to delete your question, but you can edit it. It's not a bad question in my opinion. You might consider Toshinou's answer if you want to edit it.

Comment: thx reopen it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I voted to close the question because as I read it, the question wasn't really asking for the difference between manga and comics, but was asking for a list of design characteristics. I personally think of these as two separate concerns. (How can I tell the difference vs design features).

I think design features are too broad as there are hundreds of stylistic items that could be included in an answer, and may not apply to certain manga

The question also asks to compare the features over time.

I think A&M does have a slight bandwagonning tendency when it comes to closure votes.

I would vote to reopen the question if:

- the part about design over time was removed/turned into a new question
- The question was clearer about if they wanted "characteristics of a manga" or "differences between manga and comics"

I could be completely wrong in this thought process and of there is a significant reopen movement I will retract my close vote, but the question could really do with some revision anyway

Edit: (looks good now :) )